# Frames in HTML?

Tags: asp.net

Actually...im having one left frame and one right frame....

1. In Left Frame , i'm having one treeview (which is static)
2. In Right Frame , based on the click (that is based on the selected child i have to show the corresponding web page )

How to achieve this ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a frameset

```
<frameset cols="150,*" frameborder="NO" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>
    <frame src="left.html" frameborder="NO" >
    <frame src="right.html" frameborder="NO" name="subwindow">
</frameset>

<noframes>
   <body><p>This web page uses frames.</p></body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
```

and make your links to target window like;

```
<A HREF="main.html" target="subwindow">
```